# How to loop through a list when running an API from graphQL

Tags: r, loops, graphql

I am trying to extract data from an Norwegian API using GraphQL in **R** in which I have to specify a traffic registration point and a period (from datetime - to datetime). This works ok, but since there are many different registration points, I would like to run this as a loop to extract data from all these points and add them to one data frame in **R**. There seem to be something wrong with my code, which is expected since I am new to these things. Still would appreciate some help to get it sorted.

The initial API for extracting the data is this:

```
install.packages("ghql")
install.packages("httr")


library(tidyr)
library(httr)
library(ghql)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

link <- 'https://www.vegvesen.no/trafikkdata/API/'

# R6 class for constructing graphql queries
conn <- GraphqlClient$new(url = link)

## Define query
## Create a query class first
qry <- Query$new()

## The graphQL server schema - hourly
qry$query('x', '{
trafficData(trafficRegistrationPointId: "44656V72812") {
volume {
  byHour(
    from: "2022-05-01T00:00:00+02:00"
    to: "2022-05-04T23:00:00+02:00"
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        from
        to
        total {
          volumeNumbers {
            volume
          }
          coverage {
            percentage
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
       ')

## Execute the query
res <- conn$exec(qry$queries$x)

# Convert the the output from raw to json format
res <- jsonlite::fromJSON(res,
                        flatten = TRUE)


## convert the from json to dataframe object
res_data <- res$data$trafficData$volume$byHour$edges %>%
as_tibble()

# Adds the ID to each of the rows
res_data$PointId <- "44656V72812" 

## Inspect the first 10 rows of the data
res_data
```

In the next step I extract the different IDs I need to loop through to for aggregating all data.

```
  ## The graphQL server schema - traffic registration points
  qry$query('z', '{
  trafficRegistrationPoints(searchQuery: { roadCategoryIds: [E] }) {
  id
  name
  location {
  coordinates {
    latLon {
      lat
      lon
     }
      }
     }
    }
   }
      ')

 ## Execute the query
 res3 <- conn$exec(qry$queries$z)

 # Convert the the output from raw to json format
 res3 <- jsonlite::fromJSON(res3,
                         flatten = TRUE)


 ## convert the from json to dataframe object
 res3_data <- res3$data$trafficRegistrationPoints %>%
 as_tibble()


 ## Inspect the first 10 rows of the data
 res3_data

 # Select first variable as a list

 my_list1 <- list(res3_data$id)            # Convert one column to list element
 my_list1                             # Print list
```

And here comes the one that fails:

```
# create loop

all_ids <- data.frame()
for (i in my_list1) {
qry <- Query$new()
Sys.sleep(1)

## The graphQL server schema - hourly
qry$query('x', '{
trafficData(trafficRegistrationPointId: "i") {
volume {
  byHour(
    from: "2022-05-01T00:00:00+02:00"
    to: "2022-05-04T23:00:00+02:00"
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        from
        to
        total {
          volumeNumbers {
            volume
          }
          coverage {
            percentage
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
}
      ')

## Execute the query
res <- conn$exec(qry$queries$x)

# Convert the the output from raw to json format
res <- jsonlite::fromJSON(res,
                          flatten = TRUE)


## convert the from json to dataframe object
ids <- res$data$trafficData$volume$byHour$edges %>%
  as_tibble()
ids$PointId <- "i"

all_ids <- rbind(all_ids, ids)
}
```

Both ids and naturally also `all_ids` seems to be empty.

Any ideas what went wrong?

I was expecting the loop to do multiple extractions of data for each id.

Comment: As a first guess, I think `i` needs to be replaced by its value in your final query.  So replace `... trafficData(trafficRegistrationPointId: "i") ... ` with `paste0(... trafficData(trafficRegistrationPointId: ', i, '") ...)`.

Comment: Hi. Thank  you so much for helping out. I have tried to alter the code to: ...  'qry$query('x', '{
trafficData(trafficRegistrationPointId: ', i, '")  {
    volume {
      byHour( ...  ' But it didn't like it and I got an error message like : **... Error in qry$query("x", "{\ntrafficData(trafficRegistrationPointId: ",  : 
  unused arguments (i, "\")  {\n    volume {\n      byHour(\n       ... **